# Managing breaking changes when upgrading application to ASP.Net vNext

Tags: asp.net

I understand that ASP.Net vNext is still in early preview, but I keep hearing mention that:

> the ASP.NET team had to include breaking changes in vNext.

ref: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio

Based on what we know today, do we have any idea about what will be involved when we need to upgrade to the next version of ASP.Net? What breaking changes will need to be attended to manually?

Answer (score 0):

So I don't believe that Asp.Net vNext is finished enough to be able to answer this question.  Watching the Repos a lot of the namespaces/methods are still getting refactored/moved around.

This being said it is important to understand that vNext is a complete re-write of MVC and WEB API.  A lot of the conventions are the same so most of your Views won't need to be changed but any code that relies on HttpContext.Current or anything else from the System.Web namespace will have to be refactored as vNext will no longer be using System.Web.